# Aspect name in Alfresco showing up as undefined in 'Manage Aspect'

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-enterprise

I was working with Alfresco-entreprise 4.1.1.3 and i moved to alfresco-community 5.0.2.

In this migration i copied all the config files of my custom aspects to the same locations as it was in 
Alfresco-entreprise 4.1.1.3

I have set them to visible in share UI and I can see them in the share UI.

The problem is that when I right click on a site or folder and choose 'Manage Aspect', i see that the aspect name is listed as

> undefined (gifapidocument:MyAspect)

I am not sure why it is showing up as undefined. When I click on manage rules -> add aspect , I see that the name is showing up correctly.

When i try to add a document to Alfresco from my application it works but the document is added without any properties and empty Aspects.

the paths of my configs are :

> **share-config-custom.xml :** ./tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/web-extension

- In **`<alfresco-config><config><aspects><visible>`**, i added :

  `<aspect name="gifapidocument:*MyAspect*" />`
- In **`<alfresco-config><config><forms><form>`**, i added :

```
<field-visibility>

   <show id="gifapidocument:typeDocumentXXXX" />

</field-visibility>

<field-visibility>

    <show id="gifapidocument:idXXXXXXXX" />

</field-visibility>
```

another path of my configs :

> **myAppDocument-model.xml :** ./tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension/myApp/model

- In **`<model><aspects>`**, i added :

```
<aspect name="gifapidocument:*MyAspect*">

<properties>

  <property name="gifapidocument:typeDocumentXXXX">

    <type>d:text</type>

    <mandatory>false</mandatory>

  </property>

  <property name="gifapidocument:idXXXXXXXX">

    <type>d:text</type>

    <mandatory>false</mandatory>

  </property>

</properties>

</aspect>
```

and finaly :

> **myApp.properties :** ./tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension/myApp/messages

i added :

```
aspect.gifapidocument_*myAspect*=GIF-API-MYAPP-*myAspect*
```

Answer (score 0):

u can check yours aspects with:

```
yourhost/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/nodes/{{uiid}
```

it is shown  in this properties"aspectNames": []
in my case when i click to manage aspect i cant see any thing in share but the aspect is added correctly.

Comment: unfortunately, its not my case and idk why my aspects are undefined !

Answer (score 0):

Could the asterisks be in the name of aspect?